# How to configure SSH for Vagrant environment?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I prepared a cluster of 4VM's with this Vagrantfile.

```
hosts = {
"n1" => "192.168.77.10",
"n2" => "192.168.77.11",
"n3" => "192.168.77.12",
"n4" => "192.168.77.13"
}

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
# always use Vagrants insecure key
    config.ssh.insert_key = false
# forward ssh agent to easily ssh into the different machines
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    check_guest_additions = false
    functional_vboxsf = false
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"

    hosts.each do |name, ip|
     config.vm.define name do |machine|
      machine.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip
      machine.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
       v.name = name
      end
     end
    end
end
```

Now I have four running virtual machines.
After vagrant ssh n4,my next step is to ssh to other machines,but I can not manage. I tried this

```
vagrant ssh vagrant@192.168.77.10
The machine with the name 'vagrant@192.168.77.10' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

I already posted question regarding denied permission

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.77.12
vagrant@192.168.77.12: Permission denied (publickey).
```

This example is from Mastering Kubernetes book.(Gigi Sayfan)
I am not sure if I have permissions problem or something else. I can not find similar examples.

I tried then

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ vagrant ssh vagrant@n1
The machine with the name 'vagrant@n1' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

This does not work either

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ ssh vagrant@n1
ssh: Could not resolve hostname n1: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I really do not understand what is going on.

My config

```
vagrant ssh-config
Host n1
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/miki/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes

Host n2
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2200
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/miki/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes

Host n3
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2201
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/miki/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes

Host n4
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2202
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/miki/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
```

If I try

```
ssh -vvv vagrant@n1
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "n1" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname n1: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Gerald suggested this

```
vagrant ssh n1
```

Output

```
The machine with the name 'n1' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with vagrant, but the error message `The machine with the name 'vagrant@n1' was not found configured` suggests that vagrant does not support the `username@host` notation at this place. The username is already provided in the `vagrant ssh-config`. I would try `vagrant ssh n1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your `vagrant up` folder, use `vagrant ssh n1`
2. It seems that you are using the default ssh key with `config.ssh.insert_key = false` setting, then use `ssh vagrant@192.168.77.10 -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` might work for you.